# Как получить ответ на POST запрос, используя fetch?

Tags: javascript

**Как получить ответ на POST запрос, используя fetch ?**

Пробую так.

```js
fetch('url', {
  method: 'post',
  body: 'body' })
.then ( (responce) );
```

Comment: Если http://learn.javascript.ru/fetch не обманывает, то так: 

`.then(function(response) {  
    return response.json();  
  }).then(function(responce) { alert(responce.field); })`  где вместо `json` могут быть другие форматы (text, json, formData, blob, arrayBuffer)

Comment: И что по-вашему должна делать вот эта конструкция `(responce)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `fetch` возвращает *обещание* (Promise). Это обещание будет *выполнено успешно* (resolve) с объектом ответа в качестве аргумента и *отклонено* (reject) в случае ошибки. На этом этапе нет абсолютно никакой разницы между POST и GET запросами.

```
fetch(request).then(function(response) {
    // Ответ получен.
}).catch(function(error) {
    // Произошла ошибка.
});
```

При необходимости, вы можете производить любые действия с объектом `response`, используя его [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response).

Дополнительно стоит обратить внимание, что ответ сервера с кодом вне диапазона [200, 299] *не является ошибкой* с точки зрения `fetch`.

---

Итак, если предположить, что сервер возвращает данные в формате JSON, то можно использовать вот такой код:

```
fetch('url', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'foo=bar'
}).then(function(response) {
    // Стоит проверить код ответа.
    if (!response.ok) {
        // Сервер вернул код ответа за границами диапазона [200, 299]
        return Promise.reject(new Error(
            'Response failed: ' + response.status + ' (' + response.statusText + ')'
        ));
    }

    // Далее будем использовать только JSON из тела ответа.
    return response.json();
}).then(function(data) {
    // ... Делаем что-то с данными.
}).catch(function(error) {
    // ... Обрабатываем ошибки.
});
```